# Laravel search query - SQL ordering of 'OR' and 'AND' ruining foreach loop query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, pagination

I am having problems with my search function working properly.  Currently, I have a search form with two radio buttons('keywords' and 'exact') and depending on what they have selected, it should search the database for the given array of strings or single string(both the title AND description together SHOULD contain all of the searched keywords).  The issue arises when the user searches via keywords (a bunch of single word strings).  Presently when i fetch the string from the form, I explode it and then run a foreach loop through it, however, it ends up messing up due to SQL's ordering of 'OR' and 'AND' operators.

For instance, a search value of search_value=black+darker would $query->toSql() to

```
"select * from `animes` where `description` like ? or `name` like ? and `description` like ? or `name` like ?"
```

However, SQL reads it as

```
"select * from `animes` where (`description` like ?) or (`name` like ? and `description` like ?) or (`name` like ?)"
```

Here is my code(ignore anything related to 'genre' as that part works correctly as expected):

```
public function searchAnimes(SearchRequest $request)
{
    if($request->search_type == 'keyword')
    {
        $animeSearchValues = explode(' ', Input::get('search_value'));
    }
    elseif($request->search_type == 'exact')
    {
        $animeSearchValues[0] = Input::get('search_value');
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('animes');
    }
    $genres = $request->name;
    $query = Anime::query();

    if(isset($animeSearchValues) && strlen(Input::get('search_value')) >= 3)
    {
        foreach($animeSearchValues as $animeSearchValue)
        {
            $query->where('description', 'like', '%'.$animeSearchValue.'%')
                  ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$animeSearchValue.'%');
        }

        if(isset($genres))
        {
            foreach ($genres as $genre)
            {
                $query->whereHas('genres', function ($f) use ($genre)
                {
                    $f->where('slug', $genre);
                });
            }
        }
        $animeResults = $query->orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
        return view('animes.results', compact('animeResults'));
    }
}
```

The only solution I have been able to think of is to take both the title and description and merge them into a single string and then search through it for each individual keyword, however, that method seems to be too jerry-rigged or nonstandard.  Also, keep in mind, I need the entire thing in a single query builder as so I may display the results with pagination.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? This searches for everything that has each keyword in either title or description.

```
foreach($animeSearchValues as $animeSearchValue){
    $query->where(function ($q) use ($animeSearchValue){
        $q->where('description', 'like', '%'.$animeSearchValue.'%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$animeSearchValue.'%');
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried it, however now the $query can't read the $animeSearchValue variable for some reason.

Comment: Yes I literally just added the 'use' as I forgot to put it in (asked an answer yesterday you answered that had 'use' in it) and it works presently.  Going to test it a bit more to confirm.

Comment: Ultimately Pawel's answer and mine are the same functionally, though I'm still concerned about the placement of that dump() function call.

Comment: Yes that works perfectly.  I just confirmed with the raw sql:
    "select * from `animes` where (`description` like ? or `name` like ?) and (`description` like ? or `name` like ?)"

Comment: @dspitzle That was for testing as I put that in when I was trying to find the source of the code's failure.  I left it in while it was to run the loop so I could see it as it was working.

Comment: @LoganHasbrouck Glad it worked. To be honest, your suggestion or merging the fields is actually not bad. I myself do that using `concat` in postgres to do some "full text searches"

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty good, although I suspect that using LIKE on concat output might be slower than checking the individual fields.

Comment: That was the only solution I could come up with because I couldn't figure out how to isolate each individual foreach call from each other when the SQL statement is run.  I wanted to avoid that as it seemed to me to be rather unorthodox.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use whereNested() so you can control the grouping of the conditions.  Check out Dayle Rees' [page on Eloquent queries](http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-queries) for details

EDIT:  To clarify, I think you'd want to replace

```
  foreach($animeSearchValues as $animeSearchValue)
    {
        $query->where('description', 'like', '%'.$animeSearchValue.'%')
              ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$animeSearchValue.'%');
        dump($query->get(), $animeSearchValue);
    }
```

with

```
  foreach($animeSearchValues as $animeSearchValue)
    {
      $query->whereNested( function($query) use($animeSearchValue)
        {
          $query->where('description', 'like', '%'.$animeSearchValue.'%')
                ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%'.$animeSearchValue.'%');
        }
       dump($query->get(), $animeSearchValue);
    }
```

The benefit of using whereNested is that each instance is ANDed together in the main query, so each of the individual keywords are then required to appear in one of either the description or name fields.  Your example would then be parsed as:

```
"select * from `animes` where (`description` like ? or `name` like ?) and (`description` like ? or `name` like ?)"
```

Comment: Blah... I can't view it because it's blocked where I am at by the county web filter under the 'downloads' category haha.  If I don't find a solution by the time I leave for the day, I'll check it out when I get home.  Thanks.